# Ubuntu disk full after running photorec

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, testdisk, photorec

I ran `testdisk` and `photorec` when attempting to recover a deleted file.
When I ran `testdisk`, I selected the option to create a log file and it aborted because the `disk was full`. I deleted the `testdisk.log` file and used the `photorec` without a log file.

The `photorec` filled the disk space and recovered some files to a directory, I found lots of recfnd directories but only the first one had content which did not match the directory that I was looking for. So, I deleted the directory and `photorec.ses` file.

It still says that my disk is full and does not allow me to perform any operations.

Disk Utility Analyzer still provides me with info saying that for the partition `/` the data is `13.2 GB/40.2GB`

`sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100M -exec du -sh {} ';' | sort -rh | head -n50` reveals the information:

```
250M    /var/crash/_usr_share_code_code.1000.crash
149M    /opt/android-studio/lib/idea.jar
120M    /var/crash/_opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
108M    /opt/google/chrome/chrome
```

My disks:

```
/boot/efi(13.9% full) 273MB
/dev/sda2 17MB Microsoft Reserved
/dev/sda3 861 GN Windows
/dev/sda5 41GB(34.1% full) Linux Filesystem
/dev/sda6 16GB Linux Swap
/dev/sda7 80GB(82.18% full) 
/dev/sda4 1GB Microsoft Windows Recovery Environment
```

Comment: It sounds like your hard disk is simply full.  Do you have any reason to believe this isn't the case?

Comment: Disk Utility Analyzer still provides me with info saying that for the partition / the data is 13.2 GB/40.2GB and it lists home folder seperately.

Comment: What are your other mounted partitions, and what device is testdisk/photorec recovering from?

Comment: I am trying to recover from the same disk as the one which was mounted which is the root file system.

Comment: While this doesn't really answer your question of why this is happening, testdisk/photorec is not really set up for restoring from a partition that's currently mounted, it might be better to do so from a bootable live USB.

Comment: I removed `image.dd` files from a couple of locations and it started working again.

Comment: “when attempting to recover a deleted file” Said file was not on the same Ubuntu partition, right?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto it was on the same partition, there were files on the partition from running `testdisk`, `photorec` and `extundelete`.

Comment: @vamsiampolu by running those tools on the same partition you basically started overwriting the data you wanted to restore with extracted data that may or may not have been related.